# Python Script Referencing or Calling

Tags: python, import

I have 2 python files (.py) named fileA and fileB.

```
# file A has the following codes:

import Pandas as pd
x = input (x)
z = input (y)
y = x + z

if y == 8:
    fileB() 
# Call or run file B
# ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
# file B has the following codes:
# x and y are from file A
a = x + y     
c = a + z
print (c)
```

Question: I want to import file B into A and run file A

```
# I have tried to use the following:

# into file A
from  fileB import* 

# and also from fileA import* #
# into file B so I can use some variables in file A.

# But I get errors as name x and y are not defined for fileB
```

Comment: "But I get errors." is completely unclear. Please show us what errors exactly are you getting. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Updated with the error description

Comment: you have to create functions and import them. If you're coding at top level, importing the module itself will run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a function in file B that does the maths it schould work:

```py
def funB(x, z):
    a = x + y     
    c = a + z
    return c
```

then you can import that funcion in file A like:

```py
from fileB import funB
if ...:
    print(funB(x, y))
```